# FOR XML is generating a empty first line

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, xml, sqlcmd

I'm parsing with flash a XML file generated by this code:

```
:XML ON  
USE MyDatabaseName 
GO 
SET NOCOUNT ON 

SELECT * FROM ProgramacionDia as programa order by hora 
FOR XML AUTO,
ROOT ('toflash'), 
ELEMENTS 

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

But I get a XML file with the first line empty. Removing this first empty line in the generated XML works ok with flash, but with the generated XML no.

How can I remove that line? Is my script wrong? I have no much idea about this code.

I'm running SQL Server 9.0.

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of trial and error, I found this is caused by the `USE` statement occuring after XML mode is turned on. I have no idea why; I assume it's simply an artifact of `sqlcmd` processing.

Here are three solutions I came up with from playing around with the code:

1. Remove the `USE` completely, and specify the database name on the command line using the `-d` parameter instead.

   ```
   :XML ON  

   SET NOCOUNT ON 

   SELECT * FROM ProgramacionDia as programa order by hora 
       FOR XML AUTO, ROOT ('toflash'), ELEMENTS 

   SET NOCOUNT OFF
   ```
2. Remove the `USE` completely, and three-part-name the table.

   ```
   :XML ON  

   SET NOCOUNT ON 

   SELECT * FROM [MyDatabaseName]..[ProgramacionDia] as programa order by hora 
       FOR XML AUTO, ROOT ('toflash'), ELEMENTS 

   SET NOCOUNT OFF
   ```
3. Move the `USE` statement *above* the `:XML ON` directive, and delete the `GO` (this will suppress the "Changed database context to 'MyDatabaseName'" message in the output). I have no idea why this also fixes the issue.

   ```
   USE MyDatabaseName

   :XML ON  

   SET NOCOUNT ON 

   SELECT * FROM ProgramacionDia as programa order by hora 
       FOR XML AUTO, ROOT ('toflash'), ELEMENTS 

   SET NOCOUNT OFF
   ```

Depending on what your actual script looks like, one of these options should be adaptable for you.